# Delete table which has entries and it is referred to the other table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to delete the table(example:artist) which has entries, and the primary key(ex:ar_id) of artist table is referred to the other table(ex:songs). I want to delete the artist table and the entries in the table is to be reallocated to other table by asking the user in front-end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete table which is related to other table , you should change the relation between them and set primary key on delete(cascade,set null,no action).

Answer (score 0):

If you want delete 'artist' table and move records into another table:

1. Create a new table
2. Copy records into new table
3. Drop foreign keys to 'artist' table
4. Create foreign keys to new table
5. Drop 'artist' table